# Sqlalchemy flush and commit for ORM objects and mysql metadata locks

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

When I am querying the ORM object with no commits or flush and then trying to truncate the table I am getting `metadata lock` in DB.

I am assuming that the `session.query(OBJ).all()` it's a DQL command and `SELECT` has shared lock only when the transaction is in progress and the problem seems that I am misunderstanding the root cause of this problem (For now I think that I am starting shared lock with select statement and until I commit my changes I'll have this issue).

What I did to check how it works:

```
s = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autocommit=Fasle, autoflush=False)
session = s()
session.query(OBJECT).all()
time.sleep(100)
```

And in the second terminal I've run:

```
s = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autocommit=Fasle, autoflush=False)
session = s()
session.execute('TRUNCATE table OBJECT.__tablename__')
session.commit()
```

And I see `Waiting for table metadata lock` in my process list. Can somebody point me in the right direction or explain why commit is required to this kind of select?

Comment: I'm no MySQL expert, but it seems that TRUNCATE in MySQL is implemented so that it is blocked by readers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42835275/metadata-lock-on-mysql-5-7-cant-find-locking-process, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37306568/how-to-solve-mysql-innodb-waiting-for-table-metadata-lock-on-truncate-table. From the comments to one of the answers: "TRUNCATE TABLE is sort of a hybrid of DDL and DML in MySQL, and happens outside the scope of InnoDB's MVCC, so it can't be done with any read snapshot referencing the table -- the snapshot would be useless, hence a metadata lock."

Comment: Thanks, my question was more about why after query ORM object the transaction wasn't close. And I think Sqlalchemy is using `select for update` statements to work with objects and provide an ability to change rows. So in this case, all of these rows will be locked for all DML and DDL statements. But I can't find if this is true :(

Comment: The session does not close the transaction on its own as long as it is in scope and you don't play with autocommit, you must explicitly control the tx. SQLA does not by default use SELECT ... FOR UPDATE, again you have to explicitly use it. From the linked Q/A it seems that TRUNCATE is indeed blocked by concurrent txs, even if they only read, due to its implementation details in MySQL.

Comment: yes, I was wrong about SELECT ... FOR UPDATE. Seems in this case I need to do a commit after each select statement to avoid `metadata lock timeout` issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the statement, s = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autocommit=Fasle, autoflush=False), is autocommit=Fasle by mistake. Make it autocommit=False. Otherwise, I dont see any other error. Can you share the error?

Comment: The problem is that `TRUNCATE` statement is hanging and I see that this query is `Waiting for table metadata lock` if I am doing `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` And I want to understand why querying the table without commit and flush is locking the DDL command.

Comment: I think this should help.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37306568/how-to-solve-mysql-innodb-waiting-for-table-metadata-lock-on-truncate-table?noredirect=1&lq=1